# <h:inputText inside <t:datatable not set

Tags: jsf, datatable, textinput

i am new to JSF.

i have a problem with  tag my .jsp page is like this:

```
<h:form id="form1">
                <t:inputHidden id="primaryKey"
                    value="#{EditConfigurationBean.primaryKey}" forceId="true" />
                <t:inputHidden id="beanName"
                    value="#{EditConfigurationBean.beanName}" forceId="true" />
                <t:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{EditConfigurationBean.config}"  rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="rowvar"
                    rowClasses="standardTable_Row1,standardTable_Row2" 
                    columnClasses="standardTable_Column1,standardTable_Column2,standardTable_Column3">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <f:verbatim>
                                        <object width="0px" height="0px"></object>
                                    </f:verbatim>
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="Entry Name" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{rowvar.bean.name}"></h:outputLabel>
                        </h:column>
                        <t:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <f:verbatim>
                                        <object width="0px" height="0px"></object>
                                    </f:verbatim>
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="Entry Value" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:inputText styleClass="inputText" value="#{rowvar.value}"></h:inputText>
                        </t:column>
                    </t:dataTable>
                        <t:htmlTag value="div" styleClass="commandBar">

        <h:commandButton onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" action="#{EditConfigurationBean.back}" id="navigation" immediate="true" value="back" styleClass="commandButton" />

        <h:commandButton onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" action="#{EditConfigurationBean.update}" value="Update" styleClass="commandButton" />

    </t:htmlTag>
            </h:form>
```

and my backbean code is:

```
public class ConfigurationEditBean{
    public String getInit(){
        try {
            config = loadConfig();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (config != null)
            this.entriesCount =this.config.size();
        return "";
    }
    private int primaryKey;
    private java.lang.String beanName;
    private int entriesCount;
    private List<ConfigurationFullEntry> config;

    public int getEntriesCount() {
        return entriesCount;
    }

    public void setEntriesCount(int entriesCount) {
        this.entriesCount = entriesCount;
    }

    public void setConfig(List<ConfigurationFullEntry> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public int getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }

    public void setPrimaryKey(int primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }

    public java.lang.String getBeanName() {
        return beanName;
    }

    public void setBeanName(java.lang.String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }
    private List<ConfigurationFullEntry> loadConfig() throws Exception{
        List<ConfigurationFullEntry> entriesList = new ArrayList<ConfigurationFullEntry>();
            //do load from DB
        return entriesList;
    }
    public List<ConfigurationFullEntry> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
    public String update(){
        return "";
    }
    public String back(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

the problem is that page display correctly but when i am change value of one

tags and submit the form, corresponding setXXX of backbean is not called.

also when i have tried an inputtext tag outside of

wha's wrong about my codes?
thanks in advance

---

**Update:** this is my generated HTML no nested form exist within it.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head><base href="http://localhost:7001"><title>My JSF 'ConfigurationEditor.jsp' starting page</title></head><body><form id="j_id_id2" name="j_id_id2" method="post" action="/HealthMonitorConsole/ConfigurationEditor.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"><input type="hidden" id="primaryKey" name="primaryKey" value="0"><input type="hidden" id="beanName" name="beanName" value="com.pardis.healthMonitor.dm.service.ServiceBean"> <table><thead><tr><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Value</th></tr></thead><tbody id="j_id_id2:j_id_id5:tbody_element"><tr><td>Server</td><td><input id="j_id_id2:j_id_id5:0:j_id_id13" name="j_id_id2:j_id_id5:0:j_id_id13" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><td>arash</td><td><input id="j_id_id2:j_id_id5:1:j_id_id13" name="j_id_id2:j_id_id5:1:j_id_id13" type="text" value=""></td></tr></tbody></table><br> 
<input id="j_id_id2:j_id_id14" name="j_id_id2:j_id_id14" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="if(typeof window.getScrolling!='undefined'){oamSetHiddenInput('j_id_id2','autoScroll',getScrolling());}"> <input type="hidden" name="autoScroll"> <input type="hidden" name="j_id_id2_SUBMIT" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="8EgC7hvJoXWgMHaUZxk5rx66APlnNueyP32ajDxbvc/i5akMf2jX5SQ5BLInRDoWgWvcMUADuXlYwCWVxYrNWghZBdlolM+1zLfQTh4aUm4="></form>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

    function getScrolling()
    {
        var x = 0; var y = 0;if (self.pageXOffset || self.pageYOffset)
        {
            x = self.pageXOffset;
            y = self.pageYOffset;
        }
         else if ((document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft)||(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop))
        {
            x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
         else if (document.body) 
        {
            x = document.body.scrollLeft;
            y = document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        return x + "," + y;
    }

//--></script>
</body></html>
```

i am writing every thing like tutorial examples but it does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that exactly the same datamodel is preserved during the apply request values phase of the form submit as it was during the render response phase of the initial page display. A normal place is to do the preloading is the constructor of the backing bean.

```
public class Bean {
    private List<Item> items;

    public Bean() {
        items = itemDAO.list();
    }

    // ...
}
```

An alternative is to put the bean in the session scope, but this has more impact on user experience.

Since you're using Tomahawk, you can also just set the `preserveDataModel` attribute of the `t:dataTable` to `true` like so:

```
<t:dataTable preserveDataModel="true">
```

This will store the datamodel in the view's component tree (which in turn is stored in the session scope) so that exactly the same datamodel is available in the subsequent request.

#### See also:

- [Using Datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html)

Comment: thank for your reply and your useful tutorial but it didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: Is the generated HTML valid? I.e. there is no nested `<form>` element?

Comment: comment's length is not enough so i post a new answer!

Comment: Well, then I don't see other possible causes than wrong data loading logic. I.e. the preserved datamodel is not the same. Did you try putting the whole bean in session scope as a test? You only need to ensure that your getters are just returning data and not doing anything else. Data loading ought to be done in constructors or at highest by lazy loading.

Comment: Since you're using Tomahawk's datatable, you could also try to set its `preserveDataModel` attribute to `true`.

Comment: sorry again!
i am new to JSF. let me talk more about my problem. i want to implement dynamic key-value editor. my editor must be able to edit a list of key-value attributes based on model of collection(list of attribute names, their types and their values) the model is saved on two DB tables one master table for model and one detail table for attributes. i have written my bean (above) to encapsulate my model functionality. my managed bean in faces-config.xml has two parameter that gets from url like #{param.primaryKey} i pass model id and model type to my jsf page and i expect to edit it!

Comment: my model show correctly but i could not edit it because JSF binding of inputtext tag not work and does not call the setXXX method of my bean!

Comment: The setters won't be called when the data model is loaded at the wrong moment in the JSF lifecycle. See [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html). The data model MUST have been loaded *before* the second phase of the form submit. Did you try `preserveDataModel="true"` anyway?

Comment: :( i am new to JSF, i dont understand what you said about "wrong moment in the JSF lifecycle" as i siad before when i put <inputtext tag outside the <datatable tag every things works fine but when i put it inside it does not call setter! what should i do?! :( :( :'(

Comment: As said, either set `preserveDataModel="true"`, or load datamodel in bean constructor, or put bean in session scope (and do NOT load in a getter, unless lazy loading). All boils down that the same datamodel should be preserved during apply request values phase of the form submit as it was during render response phase of the initial request. I've given enough links. I suggest to put the current project aside and create a brand new playground project based on the code/lessons in the given links and play around until you understand it. Then apply the newly learnt things on your current project.

Comment: you were right! the problem has been solved by preserveDataModel="true" thanks again